# Java Reflection not working and getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, tomcat, reflection, tomcat7

I have a Servlet class which do some dynamic class initialization and method invocation using reflection. It has the following code to do that.

```
@Override
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String reqActionContext = PageContextHelper.getFunctionName( "login" );
         // Trace reqActionContext
        System.out .println("reqActionContext : " + reqActionContext );
        // Get the page context related class object
        Object contextClass = PageContextHelper.getContextBoundedClass( "authentication");
        Class < ? >[ ] paramTypes = new Class < ? >[2];

        paramTypes[0] = HttpServletRequest.class ;
        paramTypes[1] = HttpServletResponse.class ;

        // Is there a class associated with the current context
        if ( contextClass != null ) {
            // Trace contextClassSystem. out .println("Contextclass : " + contextClass);
            // get the Class
            Class < ? > thisClass = contextClass.getClass();
            // Trace thisClass
            System.out .println("thisClass : " + thisClass );
            // get the method
            Method contextMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod( reqActionContext, paramTypes );

            if ( contextMethod != null ) {
                contextMethod.invoke ( contextClass, request, response );
            }
        }
    }  catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( InvocationTargetException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The class which get the context bounded class has the following code :
**PageContextHelper.java**

```
public class PageContextHelper {

    private static final String CONTEXT_CLASS_SUFFIX = "ContextHelper" ;

    private static final String CONTEXT_CLASS_PACKAGE = "com.proj.context." ;

    /**
    * Get the base path related context class object.
    *
    *@param basePath
    *@return
    */
    public static Object getContextBoundedClass ( String basePath ) {
        Class < ? > classOBJ = null ;

        try{

            if(basePath != null && !basePath.isEmpty() && basePath.length() > 1 ) {
                basePath = basePath .substring( 0,1 ).toUpperCase() + basePath.substring( 1 ).toLowerCase();
            }
            // Get the class object
            classOBJ = Class.forName( CONTEXT_CLASS_PACKAGE + basePath + CONTEXT_CLASS_SUFFIX);
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            // Do nothing and return null object
        }
        return classOBJ;
    }

    .....

}
```

The class which is looking for is `com.proj.context.AuthenticationContextHelper` and it has the following content :
**com.proj.context.AuthenticationContextHelper**

```
package com.proj.context;

    public class AuthenticationContextHelper{

    public void loginProcess (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        try {
            // Do some processing here
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            // TODO : Remove this trace line and do something meaningful
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code get the following trace :
Trace

```
reqActionContext :loginProcess 
Contextclass : class com.proj.context.AuthenticationContextHelper
thisClass : class java.lang.Class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Class.loginProcess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
        at com.proj.servlet.ContentServlet.doGet(ContentServlet.java:81)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
...
```

It says **NoSuchMethod** but the method is there in the class `com.proj.context.AuthenticationContextHelper`.

Am I missing any basic here or something wrong in the code?

The environment I am using is **Java 1.6.0_32** and **Tomcat 7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `Class` object from `getContextBoundedClass()` and getting that into an `Object` here:

```
Object contextClass = PageContextHelper.getContextBoundedClass( "authentication");
```

Instead say this:

```
 Class contextClass = PageContextHelper.getContextBoundedClass( "authentication");
```

You dont call `contextClass.getClass()` again. Instead to get an instance of a class you call `contextClass.newInstance()` to create an instance of that object and use that while invoking the method. Read this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: Changing the `contextClass` reference to type `Class` and calling `contextClass.newInstance()` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your `doGet()` method you have:

```
contextMethod.invoke ( contextClass, request, response );
```

You are passing a `contextClass` which is type Class. You need to pass it an *instance of that class* that you want the method to be called on, not a Class object of the class. Not sure where you have an instance of `AuthenticationContextHelper`, I don't see it anywhere in your Servlet class. If that's not possible, you *could* make the `loginProcess()` method static, and then pass a null object into `invoke(null, request, response)`.

---

> The PageContextHelper.getContextBoundedClass method returns the class AuthenticationContextHelper by calling Class.forName

It looks like it returns a `Class` Object:

```
classOBJ = Class.forName( CONTEXT_CLASS_PACKAGE + basePath + CONTEXT_CLASS_SUFFIX);
```

And when you try to create a method, you are creating a method on the class `Class`, because you call `Class.getClass()`. That's why you're getting your exception. Look at your output:

```
Contextclass : class com.proj.context.AuthenticationContextHelper
thisClass : class java.lang.Class
```

They are both Class objects.

Comment: The `PageContextHelper.getContextBoundedClass` method returns the class `AuthenticationContextHelper` by calling `Class.forName` method.

Comment: @ShanthaKumara That's not what's happening, see the edit in my answer

Comment: Your point is right and the answer from @sethu solves my problem.

Comment: @ShanthaKumara or you could just make the method static, you wouldn't have to create a new instance just to call a method unless you needed to.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I forgot to add a comment how I did solve the prob. A comment has been added to the Answer.